# Django rest framework serializer fields using single API call

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a route that uses a ViewSet

```py
router.register(
    r'mapping_details',
    GlobalMappingDetailsViewSet,
    base_name='global-store-product-mappings'
)
```

This view set contains a `get_queryset` method and a serializer.

```
class GlobalMappingDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GlobalMappingDetailsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Mappings.objects.all().select_related('my_column')

class GlobalMappingDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Mappings
        fields = ('column1', 'column2')
```

I want to add 2 fields that are populated using a single API call in the response of the request. I could use `serializers.Field` but will have to make separate calls for both the fields.

Does someone know the right way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is by overriding the [Django Viewset actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions). In my case I needed to just populate the response in the fields, I overrode the `list` and `retrieve` actions and added the fields to the response.

Some sample code:

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(GlobalMappingDetailsViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
    data = response.data
    api_response = MyService.make_api_call(data.get('id'))
    data['my_new_field'] = api_response.get('response_field', '')
    return response
```